# How to create asynchronous notifications in android

Tags: android, android-notifications

What is the best practice to create a scheduled notification at some point in the future?

I have found a way using a `Service` that is triggered with a `PendingIntent` via the `AlarmManager`. In the `onCreate()` method of the `Service` I create the notification. This seems a bit like abusing the service to do something it is not supposed to be doing.

Is there another less cumbersome / more elegant method of achieving the same end? (The use case in question is giving the user a daily reminder to do something with my app)

Comment: how about a BroadcastReceiver instead of a Service?

Comment: how do these work? Are they to be prefered to using a Service? Which solution is the one that is lighter on the resources?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What is the best practice to create a scheduled notification at some point in the future?

`AlarmManager`.

> This seems a bit like abusing the service to do something it is not supposed to be doing.

Ummm...why?

> Is there another less cumbersome / more elegant method of achieving the same end?

Setting an alarm requires a total of 3 to 4 Java statements, plus one for any extra you package into the `Intent`. Processing the alarm in a `BroadcastReceiver` to go raise a `Notification` regarding the "daily reminder" should be another ~20 lines of code, plus one entry in the manifest.

Comment: I still don't get what the exact difference is between using a service or a receiver. The effect seems to be the same. (I am rather fresh to android, you might have noticed).

Comment: @Yashima: For raising a `Notification`, you could use a `BroadcastReceiver` or an `IntentService` with similar results. `BroadcastReceiver` is a lighter weight, in terms of lines of code and in terms of processing power to do the work.

Comment: Thanks. "lighter weight" was what I wanted to hear. I'll go and implement that then.